# Printout st_uid in C Programming

Tags: c, unix

So I am making a very simple program that prints out the properties of a file on a UNIX system.

I have been using stat() in order to do so.

However, I am having a bit of trouble printing out the user and the group for the file. Everything else seems to be working okay.

This is a small snippet of my code (already declared the struct):

```
stat(dir_pointer->d_name, &buf);
printf("%o %s\n", buf.st_nlink, buf.st_uid);
```

It gives me a segmentation fault every time I run this specific part of my code. Would the user and group be denoted as a string?

**EDIT 1**:

```
struct stat buf; // struct for stat
```

Comment: Show how buf is declared.

Comment: `buf` is most likely a `struct stat`, unless you're using a crappy compiler that allows code that does otherwise. However, you're passing `buf.st_uid`, of type `uid_t` to `printf`, and stating that it is a string (`"%s"`). That's most likely the cause of your `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, is it possible to change type 'uid_t' to a string so it can be outputted to 'stdout'?

Comment: @Yozuru: Just use `%i`/`%d` instead of `%s`. `printf()` will do the job of "turning it into a string".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `st_uid` member of `struct stat` is an integer of type `uid_t`, which is typically identical to `unsigned short` or `unsigned int`.  It contains the numerical uid, not a user name.

If you want to print the numeric uid, you will need to first cast it to a well-defined integer type, and use the right format descriptor with printf:

```
printf("%ld\n", (long)buf.st_uid);
```

If, on the other hand, you want to print the associated username, you will need to use the function `getpwuid` to perform the conversion:

```
struct passwd *pwd;
pwd = getpwuid(buf.st_uid);
if(pwd == NULL) {
    perror("getpwuid");
} else {
    printf("%s\n", pwd->pw_name);
}
```

Note that `getpwuid` returns a pointer to a static buffer, so you will need to save a copy of its value if you want to reuse it later.

Comment: I see! So I need to cast it first and then I could print it out. Thank you for the well written answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this line...

```
printf("%o %s\n", buf.st_nlink, buf.st_uid);
```

This happens, more or less:

> You: Hey, `printf()`!
>
> `printf()`: Yes?
>
> You: First off, I'll give you an `int`, and you should print it in octal. Then, you should print the string `" "`. Next, I'll give you a string, that is, a `const char*`, and you should print it. Lastly, print the string `"\n"`.
>
> `printf()`: I understand. Give me the first argument.
>
> You: `buf.st_nlink`.
>
> `printf()`: Now, the second one.
>
> You: `buf.st_uid`. <sub>This actually has type `uid_t` but `printf()` doesn't know that. Great!</sub>
>
> `printf()` attempts to access memory at address `0x03E8`. A [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) occurs.
>
> Kernel: Hey, what's going on in there? Some nice [interrupt handler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) told me that you're accessing invalid addresses. You don't appear to have a handler for `SIGSEGV`, so, I'm sorry, but you, PID 1223, will be terminated by `SIGSEGV`. Next time, say no to drugs.

In other words, double check that you're passing the right stuff of the right types to `printf()` each time you write a call to it.